# Translate table with a range as key, how can I do it? (Python)

Tags: python, range, key, ascii, translate

I would like to use the translate function on any character from a text that falls into a specific range from the ASCII table in order to replace each of these character with a space. I wanna do so in order to avoid writing a lot of keys with the same value (" "). This is what I tried (from a txt file):

```
for line in text.readlines():

    table = {range(33,126): " "}

    for character in line:
        line.translate(table)
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong, since it doesn't work. Also, I would like not to import any library. Thank you for your help.

Comment: *"it doesn't work"* meaning what?

Comment: what is the result of  ```table = {range(33,126): " "}``` ?  I don't think it is producing the dictionary structure you expect.

Comment: If you want to translate the printable characters in ASCII, then you want to include 126 in there, which means you need to do `range(33, 127)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a dictionary with all keys in your range with values `32` - ASCII space code automatically. So you do not need to write the dictionary by hand (if its what you meant)

```
table = {i:32 for i in range (33, 126)}
```

Comment: this works perfectly, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You cant use a range in a `dict` definition like that, because it doesn't unwrap for you.

You end up with a `dict` like `{ <<ARangeObject>>: " " }` and when python checks if the value `charecter` is in the dict, since `charecter != RangeObject`, it will always say the character is not in the translate map and you translate nothing.

You probably meant to create the dict, unrolled, like this:

```
table = { ascii_val: ord(" ") for ascii_val in range(33, 126) }
```

Comment: this works perfectly, thank you